# 3d model has this gap between head and body?

Tags: unity

My 3D model is separated into a head and a body, but I’m encountering gaps between them. Although it appears to be a lighting issue, even after removing the material, the gaps persist. Do you have any ideas on how to address this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with the normals and the shading of the engine itself. There's really not much you can do about it, unless you merge the two meshes together (which is not what you want).

There's an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175854/107676) that suggest using Blender's Data Transfer modifier to transfer vertex normals from the full/uncut model to a separated version of it, but for that you'll need the original, not-separated-yet, full model.

Keep in mind that this is a very common thing and, usually, these kinds of seams are made in occluded or barely visible areas for the same reason.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that there's "not much you can do about it". Normals are just data - you can set that data to any values you want. It would be tedious to match the normals on the head and body without the un-separated model, but not infeasible. You could even duplicate the body and head, re-join them into a full model, welding vertices, then use your glued version as the source to bake from. Still tedious, but not a huge amount of work.

Comment: Isn't that basically what the Data Transfer modifier does? @DMGregory